# configuring vscode() for user classes for php

Tags: php, class, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a PHP class that I call LoveFunctions that contains standardized code for many of the routine functions my scripts perform.  Functions like writeLogLine, pdoConnect, getLatestExecution, dumpArray, pdoTableColumns, and on and on, along with a bunch of properties like isCLI, hasTerminal, thisIsMac, thisIsLinux, et cetera.  Always I create this class with $lov = new LoveFunctions( parm, parm, parm ).

This is not unique to LoveFunctions... I have other classes with the same problem, but that one is far and away my most used.

I've been using vscode for my PHP development, and until recently, vscode was happy to validate the class properties and functions (even successfully providing predictive prompt while I type $lov->someFunctionName and telling me the parameters etc.).  Until recently.  Now, (on some of my systems) references to the class properties are indicated by vscode to be undefined variables, predictive typing has stopped for the class, and so on.  The scripts run fine, of course, but vscode stopped being OK with it.

Now if I do a vscode error check (F8), it will will stop at all $lov->property references, but $lov->function() are passed over (though parameter validation no longer takes place).

I didn't give a great deal of thought to how vscode did that in the past, but now that it's stopped I'd like to proactively get it back.  My searches regarding how to introduce my classes to vscode have not born any useful fruit. So I'm here.

What can I do to "train" vscode to look into the classes that are included by require(_once) or include(_once) scripts so that I can get that functionality back?

My environment: vscode running on Mac.... most development done via vscode ssh configuration to one of a few linux servers.  PHP debug working well on all environments.  Usually I have four vscode windows open (local [Mac], r2d2 [linux], velmicro [linux], world-facing [linux]).  *In this environment, it seems that on r2d2 retains the functionality I want (at present), while the others do not.*

I wish I could say that this happened after some action I took myself, but I don't believe that to be the case.  Maybe it was a vscode update? (It does those in its own time and way on the various systems; something else I've never quite understood completely.)